# Can i transform java classes in Django project

Tags: python, django, class

I don't have much experience with Django. I have the class diagram with 25 classes and attributes and getters and setters. And the UML Diagram of all classes.

Now i Initially design that so that i make project in java / hibernate.

But now i have to make the site in Django. so i want to know that does django also support same classes thing like java does like getters , setters.

Is there anything different in Django which i have to take into consideration which is in java and not in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really hard question to answer. Keep in mind the Django is not a language in and of itself, but is a frame work built on python. It therefor supports everything python does.

So...

**Step 1**: Learn python.

Good tutorials include:

the official python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Learn python the hard way: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ (spoiler! it's actually the easy way)

as well as many books on the subject.

**Step 2:** do the django tutorial

The tutorial is kind of basic and glosses over some things, but it's a good start.

I know this isn't the bullet point list of differences between python and java that you want, but I don't think that would really help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without seeing any code examples, so it is better yo start from the begining as **Hutch** said.

Also, java is object-oriented, python is module-based. You must learn the basic diffrences between two. Such as, using getter and setter functions are not really necessary in python and i do not see much people who uses them. Check [this](http://unclezeiv.kerid.org/2009/08/about-getters-and-setters-in-python) out...

You may also check [that](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)  for a Java vs. Python comparison...